# Post-terms-order PHP errors after update

Tags: plugins, errors

I have an issue after updating the last WP version. Now I have this errors on my dashboard:

```
Post_Terms_Order_Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth) should be compatible with Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth, ...$args) in /home/***/wp-content/plugins/post-terms-order/include/pto_walkers.php on line 135

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/***/wp-content/plugins/post-terms-order/include/pto_interface-class.php:25) in /home/***/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5946

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/***/wp-content/plugins/post-terms-order/include/pto_interface-class.php:25) in /home/***/wp-admin/includes/misc.php on line 1252

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/***/wp-content/plugins/post-terms-order/include/pto_interface-class.php:25) in /home/***/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/***/wp-content/plugins/post-terms-order/include/pto_interface-class.php:25) in /home/***/wp-includes/option.php on line 958

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/***/wp-content/plugins/post-terms-order/include/pto_interface-class.php:25) in /home/***/wp-includes/option.php on line 959
```

---

When I deactivate post-terms-order plugin, all theses errors disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

This PHP warning is related to the new update of WordPress (5.3) which had a change in Walker class.

Previously the `walker` method had 2 arguments. In the new update, it has more arguments.

In order to fix the issue, You need to change the code from `Post_Terms_Order_Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth)` to `Post_Terms_Order_Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth, ...$args)`

Note: Possibly the rests of errors are caused by the first one. As it is going to output the error, it sends headers.

Comment: thank you very much! have a good day

Comment: If it is answering your question, it will be helpful for others if you mark it as correct answer.

Comment: i will work on this today though. i'll keep you updated.